# how to change attribute name in javascript with own attribute select?

Tags: javascript, laravel, attributes

I want to change id name onclick with select id name

```
<input id="image_id_' + i + '" name="picturenum" type="text" class="deleteok col s4 m4 validate center" value="' + i + '" disabled>

<script>
$('.deleteok').on('click', function () {
     $('#image_id_' + i).attr('id' , 'image_id_' +i-1);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not change the ID dynamically.
If you need it to change and use, do it for class attribute, not id.

Comment: my class attribute use in more row

Comment: But class attribute is suitable. cannot change the id attribute because it is an identity in the page as it says.